# Is there a countable set in every ultrafilter?

Tags: real-analysis, filters

Is it true that there is a countable set in every nontrivial ultrafilter (or at least every nontrivial ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Given an uncountable set, the set of co-countable subsets is a filter, and any ultrafilter extending it cannot contain a countable set.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be an infinite set. Consider the ideal $\mathcal I$ of all countable subsets of $X$.

Then $F= \{A^c \colon A \in \mathcal I\}$ is a filter on $X$. Moreover any ultrafilter that extends $F$ manifestly cannot have any countable sets. And at least one such ultrafilter exists by Zorn's lemma.